# Erb array not updated after ajax post

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I want to display statistics in my rails app through highcharts. When the user clicks a button visible in each table row a graph will be displayed. After button is clicked, an ajax post is done with the id of the entry which is used in the database query. With the .done- callback, I'm trying to iterate through the results and adding data to the chart, but the array in the view is always empty. The results from the query is displayed correctly in the controller, but is always nil in view.

View:

```
$('.stats_btn').click(function() {
    var info = $($(this).parent().siblings("#data_id")).get()
    var data_id = parseInt(info[0].innerHTML);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/my_page/get_stats",
      data: {id: data_id}
      })
            .done(function() {
              $('#stats_modal').modal();
              <%if @stats !=nil%>
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                  chart: {
                    renderTo: "stats_chart"
                  },
                  title: {
                    text: "Stats"
                  },
                  xAxis: {
                    type: "datetime"
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                    title: {
                      text: "Hits"
                    }
              },
              tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                  return Highcharts.dateFormat("%B %e, %Y", this.x) + ': ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + " views";
                }
              },
              series: [{
                  data: [
                  <%@stats.each do |video|%>
                     <%=video.hits%>,
                  <%end%>
                  ]
                }]
            });
          <%end%>
        });


 });
```

Controller:

```
@serdata_id = params[:id]
@stats = Serdata_serkeyword.group("date(serkeywords.date)").select("count(*) as hits").joins(:serdata).where("serdata.id = ?", @serdata_id).joins(:serkeyword).where("serkeywords.id = serkeyword_id")
@stats.each do |record|
  logger.info record.hits
end
```

I know that the ruby code is executed on the server side, but when i do the ajax post a new instance of the controller is created(?), therefore the array must be initialized. Have i misunderstood how this works in Rails, and is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Comment: format your data as json in the controller and parse it in your success function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS**

Firstly, I would ensure your javascript is delegated from the `document` object, as this will ensure you're able to capture the events, regardless of whether you use `Turbolinks` or not:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".stats_btn", function() {
  // stuff here
})
```

Although this won't aid in your issue, it will help with the notorious "JS won't work because Turbolinks just refreshes the `<body>` tag, not the `<head>` tag" problem

--

**Controller**

In regards to your controller, if the server-side query is firing, it means your ajax request is getting through (which is good news). The way to fix the issue is to ensure your `ajax` handler can receive the response

Typically, you'll handle the response with the [`respond_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to) code block:

```
#app/controllers/my_pages_controller.rb
Class MyPagesController < ApplicationController
   def get_stats
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js #-> returns JS response
         format.json #-> returns JSON response
      end
   end
end
```

--

**JSON**

I would actually recommend you change the `dataType` attribute of your ajax request to `JSON`, as this means you'll be able to receive pure JSON data back:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      url: "/my_page/get_stats",
```

This will mean you can do the following:

```
#app/controllers/my_pages_controller.rb
Class MyPagesController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :json, only: :get_stats

   def get_stats
      @serdata_id = params[:id]
      @stats = Serdata_serkeyword.group("date(serkeywords.date)").select("count(*) as hits").joins(:serdata).where("serdata.id = ?",   @serdata_id).joins(:serkeyword).where("serkeywords.id = serkeyword_id")
      respond_with @stats #-> automatically encodes JSON
   end
end
```

--

**View**

I think your main issue is the way you've set up your `$.ajax` callback -

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/my_page/get_stats",
      data: {id: data_id}
      })

 .done(function() {
              $('#stats_modal').modal();
              <%if @stats !=nil%>
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                  chart: {
                    renderTo: "stats_chart"
                  },
                  title: {
                    text: "Stats"
                  },
                  xAxis: {
                    type: "datetime"
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                    title: {
                      text: "Hits"
                    }
              },
              tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                  return Highcharts.dateFormat("%B %e, %Y", this.x) + ': ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + " views";
                }
              },
              series: [{
                  data: [
                  <%@stats.each do |video|%>
                     <%=video.hits%>,
                  <%end%>
                  ]
                }]
            });
          <%end%>
        });
```

Firstly, your `.done` is not associated with any event / element, meaning it will just not run. Secondly, the `done` method (or whichever method you use to capture the response from your `ajax` only works if you pass the returned `data` to it

I would recommend using the following:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "/my_page/get_stats",
   data: {id: data_id}
   success: function(data) {
       // returned data here
   }
});
```

Also, you cannot use `@instance variables` in standard JS - you can only use `@instance variables` in *back-end* code. In your case, you should pass a JSON request to your controller & then use the `data` argument in your `success` function to handle the returned JSON object

This will ensure you're able to handle the data you need on the front-end

---

If you'd like me to be more specific with the provided code, please let me know & I'll update you!

--

**Update**

The reason why you can't use `@instance variables` in front-end JS / Ajax is only front-end. Ajax ([Asynchronous Javascript And XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))) is there to send an HTTP request "behind the scenes" - meaning that your Ajax request is just like a "pseudo" browser (IE its only front-end)

The problem you have is if you set `@instance variables` in the back-end (your controller) - as your Ajax is front-end only, it means it cannot access the `@instance variables` from the controller. This means your ajax is only able to read the data you send from your controller's backend

If you made a `js.erb` in the views folder, you'd be able to use the `@instance variables` all you need

Comment: "Also, you cannot use instance variables in standard JS - you can only use @instance variables in back-end code" - What about jQuery? I've seen several examples where instance variables are being used in order to add data to highcharts..

Comment: It's not a question of JS vs JQuery - it's a question of front-end vs back-end :) I was going to explain this actually -- let me write it for you

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I wanted to avoid JSON formatting since I've seen some really easy examples of it being done in straight-up ruby. But then again that was done in a static web page, IE without use of ajax.

Comment: JSON is just data notation - basically it sends back very simple text-based data responses to your front-end, allowing you to manipulate / use that as required